# bash looping through 2 files at the same time line by line

Tags: bash, while-loop, iteration

I must mention that I am super new to bash, therefore its syntax is a huge problem for me at the moment

What do I have?

**2 files.** For example,

**tmpp1.txt**

```
drwxrw-rw-
drwxrw-rw-
-rw-r--r--
```

**tmpp2.txt**

```
drw-rw-rw-
drwxrw-rw-
-rw-r--r--
```

What do I want?

To iterate through these 2 files at the same time so that I can compare them line by line. eg: to check if the string on line 1 of tmpp1.txt is equal to the string on line 1 of tmpp2.txt, then for lin2, line3 etc

If the strings are different, I need to state what has changed.

After reading several other posts about this on the internet and stack overflow itself, I ended up with this

```
while read p1 <&tmpp1.txt && read p2 <&tmpp2.txt; do
    if [ "$p1" != "$p2" ]
    then
      echo "A file has had the wrong permission: $p1"
      echo "This has been changed to: $p2"
    fi
done
```

This code gives an error: `./folder-stats-2.sh: line 51: tmpp1.txt: ambiguous redirect`
More exactly, in the while condition

But my sanity is gone.. I ran out of ideas. I would really appreciate some help
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't think you need the `&`s after the `<`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by using the undefined operator `<&` instead of `<`. (`<&` by itself is undefined, that is; you have to specify a file descriptor like `<&3` to be valid.) That, however, won't accomplish what you want, because the input files will be opened anew each time, resulting in you repeatedly reading the first line of each file.

Instead, you need to use two separate file descriptors, opening them *once* for the loop, so that `read` inherits the same descriptor each time through the loop.

```
while read p1 && read p2 <&3  && read p3 <&4; do
   ...
done < tmpp1.txt 3< tmpp2.txt 4< tmpp3.txt
```

`<&3` tells `read` to read from file descriptor 3 instead of file descriptor 0 (standard input, its default).

Standard input, by the way, is always file descriptor 0. You could (unnecessarily) write `read p1 <&0` and `0< tmpp1.txt`. (1 and 2 are standard output and standard error, respectively, which is why you start with 3 for additional file descriptors.)

Comment: This solved it for me. But I would like to go a bit further with my understanding. How would I go around having 3 files which I want to examine at the same time? for example tmpp3.txt with the same properties? Do these descriptors work for more than 2 files?

Comment: In theory, the number of file descriptors is unlimited. In practice, there is an OS-imposed upper limit on how many files can be opened at once. Also, `bash` reserves file descriptors 10 and above for its own use, so it's safest to only use 3-9 explicitly. (One example is when you use `{foo}< tmp.txt`; the shell allocates a file descriptor of 10 or higher and assigns the selected fd to the variable `foo`.)

Comment: alright, and syntax-wise, how would I do it? when I write the condition will it be `while read p1 && read p2 && read p3 && read p4 && read p5 <&3; do` and the done one would be `done < tmpp1.txt 3< tmpp2.txt 3< tmpp3.txt 3< tmpp4.txt 3< tmpp5.txt` ?

Comment: No, each file needs its own file descriptor, and each `read` needs its own redirection.

Comment: I understand now. So I can think of each descriptor as a counter